# H-bonding in methanol and methoxyamine

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrogen-bond

The question was to determine if the substances made H-bonding between themselves and to represent it.

In the following photos i'm showing my doubt about the H-bond in $\ce{CH3OH}$. In the solution (grey highlighted background) it is shown that $\ce{CH3ONH2}$ can make even 3 H-bonds, so can't $\ce{CH3OH}$ make the same? Just as I drew beside its relative solution?

[image: CH3OH]
[image: CH3ONH2]

Comment: That’s acetamide not methoxylamine